# Unable to import FlaUI.FlaUI3 library in pythonnet

Tags: python, python.net, flaui

I am trying to load `FlaUI` libraries using `pythonnet`. The code is able to load the `FlaUI.UIA3.dll`. However, importing `FlaUI.UIA3` namespace fails.

Here is my code,

```
import clr
import sys
dll_path = 'C:\\Users\\amit_tendulkar\\.nuget\\packages\\flaui.core\\3.2.0\\lib\\net45'
dll_path2 = 'C:\\Users\\amit_tendulkar\\.nuget\\packages\\flaui.uia3\\3.2.0\\lib\\net45'
sys.path.append(dll_path)
clr.AddReference('FlaUI.Core')
sys.path.append(dll_path2)
clr.AddReference('FlaUI.UIA3')
from FlaUI.Core import Application
from FlaUI.Core.Conditions import ConditionFactory
from FlaUI.Core.Tools import Retry
from FlaUI.UIA3 import UIA3Automation
from FlaUI.UIA3 import UIA3PropertyLibrary
```

The error I am getting is below (using command `python sample.py`),

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ToadApp.py", line 12, in <module>
    from FlaUI.UIA3 import UIA3Automation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FlaUI.UIA3'; 'FlaUI' is not a package
```

If I don't include the `FlaUI.UIA3` library then I am able to Launch the application with `Application.Launch('software.exe')`.

Here is the content of my directory containing `FlaUI3.UIA3.dll`,

```
C:\Users\amit_tendulkar>dir C:\Users\amit_tendulkar\.nuget\packages\flaui.uia3\3.2.0\lib\net45
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 8692-D75E

 Directory of C:\Users\amit_tendulkar\.nuget\packages\flaui.uia3\3.2.0\lib\net45

25-01-2022  22:28    <DIR>          .
25-01-2022  22:28    <DIR>          ..
17-07-2020  02:05           105,472 FlaUI.UIA3.dll
17-07-2020  02:05            28,095 FlaUI.UIA3.xml
               2 File(s)        133,567 bytes
```

Dotnet version (using Windows 10),

```
C:\Users\amit_tendulkar>dotnet --version
6.0.101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `FlaUI.UIA3.dll` has dependency on `Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll`.

Updating the code to the below solved my issue.

```
import clr
import sys
flaui_core_path = 'C:\\Users\\amit_tendulkar\\.nuget\\packages\\flaui.core\\3.2.0\\lib\\net45'
flaui_uia3_path = 'C:\\Users\\amit_tendulkar\\.nuget\\packages\\flaui.uia3\\3.2.0\\lib\\net45'
interop_uiautomation_path = 'C:\\Users\\amit_tendulkar\\.nuget\\packages\\interop.uiautomationclient\\10.18362.0\\lib\\net45'
sys.path.append(flaui_core_path)
clr.AddReference('FlaUI.Core')
sys.path.append(interop_uiautomation_path)
clr.AddReference('Interop.UIAutomationClient')
sys.path.append(flaui_uia3_path)
clr.AddReference('FlaUI.UIA3')
from FlaUI.Core import Application
from FlaUI.Core.Conditions import ConditionFactory
from FlaUI.Core.Tools import Retry
from FlaUI.UIA3 import UIA3Automation
from FlaUI.UIA3 import UIA3PropertyLibrary
```